# Magento 2 - “Element.disabled is not a function” Attribute Error

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, creating a configurable product using a custom attribute to create product configurations the following error occurs:

```
element.disabled is not a function
```

[image]

Comment: We experience the same problem on one of our shops and looking into it.
Can you give us some more info? We dont get this error with default magento, we imported products with firegento product importer.

Comment: Turns out,  you can't add an attribute named "content"

Answer (score 1):

In our case the problem was that we had an attribute we named `content`

Magento has an element named content so this get mixed up.

The problem was in this file:
`adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/variations/variations.js`

Line 368:
`element.disabled(true);`

This causes the problem. Because element is overwritten by our attribute that is named content. In this var is disabled() not available obv.

So what we did was console.log `element` on line 365. When we compared this with a installation with magento sample data, it became clear that magento doest support the attribute code `content` for configurable products.

What magento should do is, append an `attribute_` prefix before the attribute code so that it doesn't matter what the name is from the attribute code. So something like:

```
registry.set('attribute__prefix_' + attribute.code);
```

My colleague Elias raised an issue on github for this problem:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12555